# Flutter: ScrollEdgeListener how to use for both Start and End

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to pop my screen if the user scroll back to the start and end of my PageView.builder. However the ScrollEdgeListener (scroll_edge_listener: ^0.1.1) only allows me to either choose ScrollEdge.end or ScrollEdge.start. However, I would like to use both. See code below.

```
child: ScrollEdgeListener(
          edge: ScrollEdge.end,
          edgeOffset: 0,
          continuous: false,
          debounce: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          dispatch: true,
          listener: () {
            print('einde bereikt');
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: PageView.builder(
            controller: _pageController,
            onPageChanged: (int page) {
              setState(
                () {
                  _activePage = page;
                },
              );
            },
            itemCount: _pages.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return _pages[index % _pages.length];
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Cannot find a solution. Thank you for your help.